# PyQt5 Block Comma in QlineEdit

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, qlineedit

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QIntValidator

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Simple Main Window")
        button = QPushButton("Press Me!")

        self.cw = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.cw.setLayout(layout)

        only_int = QIntValidator()
        self.num_le = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.num_le)
        self.num_le.setValidator(only_int)

        self.button = QPushButton("Press Me!")
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.calc)

        self.show()

    def calc(self):
        print(int(self.num_le.text()))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

How can I block commas in a QlineEdit with QIntValidator? A comma is not a valid Python number and throws this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,111'

The validator allows you to enter 1,1,1,1,1,1 and converts that to 111,111 when you leave the widget.

JT

Comment: An alternative is to use QSpinBox, eventually hiding the arrows (see the [`buttonSymbols`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#buttonSymbols-prop) property).

Comment: I've figured out how to make the QSpinBox look like a QLineEdit with one exception. I can't figure out how to select the default 0 when clicking into the QSpinBox like what happens when you tab into the QSpinBox. I have >1600 widgets in my application so setting the tab order is insane.

Answer (score 0):

QIntValidator by default uses the thousand Locale to interpret values in other to enhance readability when users enter large numbers. This explains why 1111 turns 1,111, usually for human readability and not for performing computation. Read more on [QLocales](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlocale.html#setDefault).

To change this, you must set it to another locale such as the **C locale** which removes all commas and non-integers from the input, making it suitable for performing computations.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale



only_int = QIntValidator()
c_locale = QLocale(QLocale.C)
only_int.setLocale(c_locale)

self.num_le = QLineEdit()
layout.addWidget(self.num_le)
self.num_le.setValidator(only_int)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the information. It's interesting that you can still enter 1,1,1,1,1 but when you move focus to another widget it changes to 11111.